# Why do I need two escaped spaces to insert one space in statusline

Tags: statusline

I have this lines for my statusline

```
 set statusline=%{&paste?'\ \ paste\ ':''}
 set statusline+=\ %{expand('%:~:.')!=#''?expand('%:~:.'):'[No\ Name]'}
 set statusline+=%{&readonly?'\ \ [RO]':!&modifiable?'\ \ [RO]':''}
```

I removed other parts for avoiding useless complexity. As you can see, I need to put two spaces before [RO] in the third/last line when I only get one in output. Why is that?

**Edit**: My version is `NVIM v0.3.0-dev`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a `%{}` the first space character in the expression seems to be always removed.  For example, `let &statusline="%{'  ]'}"` displays the string " ]".  It also seems to be independent of `fillchars`.  That is, if `set fillchars=stl:^`, `"^]^^^^"` will be displayed.  Why this happens or if it's intentional is quite mysterious to me (hopefully someone else can answer this question).

A workaround is to use a different space character, e.g., a non breaking space 0xA0:

```
let &statusline="%{'\ua0xyz'}"
```

or

```
set statusline=%{\"\\ua0xyz\"}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't need a workaround, not really. I just wanted to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Understood, let's wait for some other answers.  I'm hoping one of the vim-airline maintainers see this, because they probably have the most experience with extreme statusline customization.